# A necessary condition for linear dependence?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$. A sufficient condition for the set of vectors

$$
\{ (1, x_1, x_1^2, \dots, x_1^{n-1}), (1, x_2, \dots, x_2^{n-1}), \dots, (1, x_n, \dots x_n^{n-1}) \}
$$

to be linearly dependent is that for exactly two scalars $x_i = x_j$, where $i \neq j$.

But is it also a necessary condition?

Comment: If you can get ${x_i}^{p} + {x_j}^{p} = {x_k}^{p}, \forall p \in \mathbb N$, then you can get linear dependence.

Comment: This means that there is yet another sufficient condition, and the mentioned sufficient condition can't be necessary?

Comment: No I don't think that it is a necessary condition.

Answer (score 3):

Those vectors form a *Vandermonde* matrix $A$. Its determinant is

$$det(A) = \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} (x_i - x_j)$$

The row vectors are linearly dependent if and only if the determinant is zero. The determinant is zero if and only if one of the factors $(x_i - x_j)$ is zero.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this valuable contribution and welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thanks. And, you're welcome :)